# Css Inner border radius

Tags: css

I need to apply an inner border radius to my component not an outer radius. I have a plain div and applied some styles to it :

```
.border {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 50px solid grey;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

Here the `border-radius` property is not doing what I expect it to do as it is applying the styles to the outside if the border not the inner part of it. Is there a way to do this using purely css and not adding any more html elements to it?

Here is a codepen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscos/pen/PojeaKE)

Comment: The curved inner border will (only) show up if the border-radius is over 50px (the thickness of the border)

Comment: But I dont want a radius to the outer border only the inner

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

You can use pseudo-element `::after` (or `::before`) and style it the way you
want it then place it on top of your `.border` div using position `absolute`.

I gave it the rounded borders you wanted then placed it in the middle, atop your `.boder` div, now it looks like the inner corners of `.border` are rounded

```css
.border {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 50px solid grey;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.border::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 240px;
  width: 390px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

Comment: You should explain what you have done to solve OP's problem. *What about this?* is not so informative.

Comment: I assumed the OP could notice the trick from seeing the after element, but I have updated my answer now with a hopefully clear explanation of what I did.

Comment: This is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a pure CSS solution, but with an extra inner div you could do this:

```css
.border {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 50px solid grey;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.outer {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="border outer">
  <div class="border inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I use another div to implement inner border. You can enjoy this code.

```css
.outer_box {
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 50px solid grey;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.inner_box {
  width: 330px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: auto auto;
  border: 8px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_box">
  <div class="inner_box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain what you have done to solve OP's problem. *How about this?* is not so informative. How can one enjoy the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `oultine` property as a border and with `::after` you can give `.border` class a background with `border-radius` which can be positioned overlapping the `.border` giving a inner border-radius look .

Used `z-index` property `-1` so that content of `.border` is not hidden behind the background.

```css
.border {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 40px solid grey;
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.border::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 18px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">ddsdggw
</div>
```